# jQuery: Parse JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I parse this?  I'm working with WordPress and jQuery.

```
{
    "MyCustomOutput": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "This is the name of the custom output",
            "version": "1.00",
            "description": "This is the Description",
            "changelog": "This is the change log history....",
            "updated": "1261274072"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried something like:

```
var d = JSON.parse(data);       
$("#version").html(data);
        $("#version").html(d.MyCustomOutput.version);
```

But I have no idea what I'm doing with jQuery or JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access data members:

```
d.MyCustomOutput[0].version
```

Also, it is helpful to use the FireBug firefox extension to debug your scripts. Just set a breakpoint to step through your code. You will have a "live" view of these data structures and can even add watches to test short code snippets to see if you are doing things correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an explanation of what you're trying to do:  http://www.json.org/js.html
When content is within `[]`, that's an array.  When content is within `{}` that's an object.

Every member of an object can be accessed via "dot notation" much like you're trying to do.  In your example, you could access version by it's object's index:
`d.MyCustomOutput[0].version`.

In other words, your object has one member: MyCustomObject.  That member has an array.  Your array has one object.

I hope that helps.